# Angularjs function calls order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown list of options, which are shown or not depending on conditions.

```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.templateType" ng-disabled="vm.status == 'sold' || vm.status == 'return' "ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in vm.templateTypes | filter:vm.isShowableTemplate"></select>
 </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
function FormOrderDialogController(tsModulesService, $scope, $q, $http, $uibModalInstance, params, $filter, Requester)                              

    Requester.restGet("/events/" + params.eventId, null, params.serverId).then((data)=>{
        vm.event = data;
    });

    Requester.restGet('/dic/10', null, null, null, true).then((resp) => {
        vm.templateTypes = resp;
        vm.templateType = vm.templateTypes[0].id;
    });    

     vm.isShowableTemplate = isShowableTemplate;

     function isShowableTemplate(templateType) {

        switch (templateType.id) {
            case 321:
                return !!vm.event.info.ticketTemplate;
            case 322:
                return !!vm.event.info.ticketETemplate;
        }
    }
```

By the time isShowableTemplate is called I expect event object to be filled, And the thing is the getEvent function is called twice, once before isShowableTemplate get called, and once after. The problem is event is undefined after the first call and I get an error "Cannot read property 'info' of undefined".
My question is why is it so and what I am doing wrong. I am new to both js and angular, so may be I miss something essential.

Comment: I would remove the filter and just have two `templateTypes` variables. `templateTypes` and `showableTemplateTypes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove the function and filter:

```
function FormOrderDialogController(tsModulesService, $scope, $q, $http, $uibModalInstance, params, $filter, Requester)                              

    Requester.restGet("/events/" + params.eventId, null, params.serverId)
        .then(data => {
            vm.event = data;

            return Requester.restGet('/dic/10', null, null, null, true);
        })
        .then(resp => {
            vm.templateTypes = resp;
            vm.showableTemplateTypes = resp.filter(t => { 
                switch (t.id) {
                    case 321:
                        return !!vm.event.info.ticketTemplate;
                    case 322:
                        return !!vm.event.info.ticketTemplate;
                }

                return false; // or true depending if you want to show the     others.
            });

            vm.templateType = vm.templateTypes[0].id;
        });   
}
```

I've combined the two `Promise`s together because you use the `vm.event` in the second response. By doing it this way, you can always guarantee some value for `vm.event`.

The html:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.templateType" ng-disabled="vm.status == 'sold' || vm.status == 'return' "ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in vm.showableTemplateTypes"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it really worked! But the question regarding double function call still remains. I am a bit confused...=)

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I can help.

Comment: It happens because Angular binds the viewmodel, so it ends up getting ran twice